# Java util.Timer get Task Execution Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, task, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way to get the thread that a TimerTask will be running on?

```
public class Main {

    static Thread gameThread= null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Timer t = new Timer();

        t.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            {
                gameThread = Thread.currentThread();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());//this will only give main thread back
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gameThread = Thread.currentThread();//unnecessary to run every time


            }

        }, 0,15);
    }
}
```

I know that this will work because the run method is declaring the thread every routine, but that seems inefficient. Is there a way I can get the thread that the task will continually run on only once? It won't work in the TimerTask's constructor or initializer because those run on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead of a Timer (recommended by Java Concurrency in Practice), this is actually pretty easy:

```
public class Main {

    static Thread gameThread= null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1 /*single-threaded executor service*/,
             new ThreadFactory(){
                  public Thread newThread(Runnable r){
                      gameThread = new Thread(r);
                      System.out.println(gameThread);
                      return gameThread;
                  }
        });


        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /*do stuff*/
            }

        }, 0,15,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

---

Links to relevant docs:

- [`Executors#newScheduledThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool(int,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)),
- [`ThreadFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html),
- [`ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))